# yaml-cpp issue: InvalidNode@YAML@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?... not found in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-linking, yaml-cpp, ros2

I am facing a runtime issue while running a C++ application in windows that links to the yaml-cpp library (yaml-cpp.lib).
**The yaml-cpp has been installed using vcpkg**.
The error has been pasted below. Please let me know if you have a hint for solving this issue.
The package dependencies have been configured using CMakeLists.txt and built using ament_cmake. The *Visual studio project created in the build folder is able to run without any problem, but this issue occurs only while running the executable using ros2 run in the terminal.*

**Error Message in pop up window**:

> radf_execution.exe - **Entry point not found** The procedure entry
> point
> "??0InvalidNode@YAML@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z"
> in the DLL "D:
> 02_Ws\ros2_ws\install\radf_execution\lib\radf_execution\radf_execution.exe"
> was not found.

Comment: I think you have some type of dll conflict / using a different version of the dll than the code was linked against. Maybe you have multiple versions of this dll on your PC and at runtime your OS is loading the wrong version.

Comment: @drescherjm : Thanks for the response. Would this mean that I have to remove from the Path (environment variables) the other locations having the dlls wil the same name?

Comment: If the other location containing dlls of the same name is in one of the folders of the PATH environment variable you probably want to remove that. You may also want to consult this documentation for where and how your OS looks for dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: @drescherjm: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried moving the priority of location containing the desired dll upwards the list of Paths in environment variables. Still this issue persists. In this case I am not linking the exe directly to a dll, but to a library named yaml-cpp.lib.

Comment: With msvc you don't link to dlls with unmanaged / standard c++ so that is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer